# Hiding one navbar and animate the other one

Tags: html, jquery, css, bootstrap-5

I currently have two separate navbars, when I click a button I want the left one to appear and disappear and the other one should move smoothly to the left side.
I have the animation working so far, however, when I click on the button which toggles the animation, the left one is smooth, but the right one (the one where I toggle) just flicks to the left side, I was wondering how I can make the animation smoother.

```
  <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#mapfliter").click(function(){
    $("#navbar_left").toggle("slide",'slow');
  });
});
</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zjctkm4d/

#mapfilter is the ID of the Button I use to toggle which is on #navbar_right
#navbar_left is the ID of the Navbar I am trying to hide, which is working fine, however, #navbar_right just snaps to the side of the screen, I'm kinda unsure how I could achieve #navbar_right moving slowly to the left side of the screen.

I hope this information is enough to help me solve my issue, please let me know if you need anything else

Comment: We currently know almost nothing about the structure of your document, so this is quite impossible to answer at this point. Questions like this should always come with a proper [mre].

Comment: Sorry, i added a fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/zjctkm4d/

Comment: The MRE really rather belongs directly into your question, not just dumped onto an external platform.

Comment: The way this slide toggle works, is that the content gets absolute positioned and then moved first, and set to display: none when the moving has finished. You should probably replace this with something, that uses a `translate` transformation, applied to _both_ navigations at the same time.

Comment: So i should not use jQuery for this?

Comment: Please see [ask]. You should be able to provide your demo _here_, and it should have proper CDN links for your resources and images from a service. It doesn't help us if you're loading libraries using relative paths that don't exist. It should also be simplified. We don't need your entire codebase.

Comment: Please tag your Bootstrap version. That's critical information. Also, see https://www.grammarly.com/blog/comma-splice. You're more difficult to understand when your paragraphs are one long sentence.

Comment: Its Bootstrap 5.2.3